# How to restore a removed default stencil in Evolus Pencil?

Tags: stencils, mockup-tool, sketching, evolus-pencil

I <strike>restored</strike> removed one of the default stencils from the `Collection Pane` (just clicked on the `close` icon). Is it deleted from the computer now or just invisible? I could download it from the Evolus Pencil Project [download page](http://code.google.com/p/evoluspencil/downloads/list?q=label%3aStencil). But can I also restore it without downloading?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The collections are not deleted, when they are "removed" by clicking on the `close` button. They just become invisible and can be enalbed again: right mouseclick on the free space in the collections area -> show hidden collections... -> click on the collection name.

[image: Evolus Pencil: show hidden collections]

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the ~/.pencil directory, and restart pencil, you will start with a fresh profile and your deleted collection will show again. Backup the dir before trying, just in case…